# Проблема с отправкой запроса в битрикс24. Открытые линии, кастомный коннектор

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, битрикс24

Помогите разобраться. пытаюсь сделать интеграцию конструктора чатботов с битрикс24. Суть интеграции в том что бы отправлять диалоги из чатов в диалоги битрикс24. как я понял что бы реализовать это мне нужно создать свой кастомный коннектор для открытой линии в битрикс24. Пишу на python3.6, для запросов использую  библиотеку requests. Доков по этой теме немного но то, что есть у меня есть. Проблема в следующем. я пытаюсь отправить запрос к битрикс API на регистрацию нового коннектора. В запросе нужно передать иконку для виджета. Передать ее нужно в svg в дата представлении. Вот моя функция для отправки запроса.

```
def imconnector_register():
    access_token = "ecff4a5e0043ff3400439ddc0000000100000395d025e9d92a164f403ee128fc7cc"
    params = {'ID': 'salebot_connector_14685c4f6f',
              'NAME': 'SalebotChatCon',
              'ICON': {
                   'DATA_IMAGE': 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_'
                                 '1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22'
                                 '%0A%09%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2070%2071%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200'
                                 '%200%2070%2071%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%230'
                                 'C99BA%22%20class%3D%22st0%22%20d%3D%22M34.7%2C64c-11.6%2C0-22-7.1-26.3-17.8C4%2C3'
                                 '5.4%2C6.4%2C23%2C14.5%2C14.7c8.1-8.2%2C20.4-10.7%2C31-6.2%0A%09c12.5%2C5.4%2C19.6'
                                 '%2C18.8%2C17%2C32.2C60%2C54%2C48.3%2C63.8%2C34.7%2C64L34.7%2C64z%20M27.8%2C29c0.8'
                                 '-0.9%2C0.8-2.3%2C0-3.2l-1-1.2h19.3c1-0.1%2C1.7-0.9%2C1.7-1.8%0A%09v-0.9c0-1-0.7-1'
                                 '.8-1.7-1.8H26.8l1.1-1.2c0.8-0.9%2C0.8-2.3%2C0-3.2c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.5-0.7s-1.1%2'
                                 'C0.2-1.5%2C0.7l-4.6%2C5.1%0A%09c-0.8%2C0.9-0.8%2C2.3%2C0%2C3.2l4.6%2C5.1c0.4%2C0.'
                                 '4%2C0.9%2C0.7%2C1.5%2C0.7C26.9%2C29.6%2C27.4%2C29.4%2C27.8%2C29L27.8%2C29z%20M44%'
                                 '2C41c-0.5-0.6-1.3-0.8-2-0.6%0A%09c-0.7%2C0.2-1.3%2C0.9-1.5%2C1.6c-0.2%2C0.8%2C0%2'
                                 'C1.6%2C0.5%2C2.2l1%2C1.2H22.8c-1%2C0.1-1.7%2C0.9-1.7%2C1.8v0.9c0%2C1%2C0.7%2C1.8%'
                                 '2C1.7%2C1.8h19.3l-1%2C1.2%0A%09c-0.5%2C0.6-0.7%2C1.4-0.5%2C2.2c0.2%2C0.8%2C0.7%2C'
                                 '1.4%2C1.5%2C1.6c0.7%2C0.2%2C1.5%2C0%2C2-0.6l4.6-5.1c0.8-0.9%2C0.8-2.3%2C0-3.2L44%'
                                 '2C41z%20M23.5%2C32.8%0A%09c-1%2C0.1-1.7%2C0.9-1.7%2C1.8v0.9c0%2C1%2C0.7%2C1.8%2C1'
                                 '.7%2C1.8h23.4c1-0.1%2C1.7-0.9%2C1.7-1.8v-0.9c0-1-0.7-1.8-1.7-1.9L23.5%2C32.8L23.5'
                                 '%2C32.8z%22/%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A',
                   'COLOR': '#a6ffa3',
                   'SIZE': '100%',
                   'POSITION': 'center'
                   },
          'ICON_DISABLED': {
                            'SIZE': '100%',
                            'POSITION': 'center',
                            'COLOR': '#ffb3a3',
                            'DATA_IMAGE': 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D'
                                          '%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20x%3D%220px%'
                                          '22%20y%3D%220px%22%0A%09%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2070%2071%22%20style%3D%22'
                                          'enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2070%2071%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22prese'
                                          'rve%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%230C99BA%22%20class%3D%22st0%22%20d%3D%'
                                          '22M34.7%2C64c-11.6%2C0-22-7.1-26.3-17.8C4%2C35.4%2C6.4%2C23%2C14.5%2C14.'
                                          '7c8.1-8.2%2C20.4-10.7%2C31-6.2%0A%09c12.5%2C5.4%2C19.6%2C18.8%2C17%2C32.'
                                          '2C60%2C54%2C48.3%2C63.8%2C34.7%2C64L34.7%2C64z%20M27.8%2C29c0.8-0.9%2C0.'
                                          '8-2.3%2C0-3.2l-1-1.2h19.3c1-0.1%2C1.7-0.9%2C1.7-1.8%0A%09v-0.9c0-1-0.7-1'
                                          '.8-1.7-1.8H26.8l1.1-1.2c0.8-0.9%2C0.8-2.3%2C0-3.2c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.5-0'
                                          '.7s-1.1%2C0.2-1.5%2C0.7l-4.6%2C5.1%0A%09c-0.8%2C0.9-0.8%2C2.3%2C0%2C3.2l'
                                          '4.6%2C5.1c0.4%2C0.4%2C0.9%2C0.7%2C1.5%2C0.7C26.9%2C29.6%2C27.4%2C29.4%2C'
                                          '27.8%2C29L27.8%2C29z%20M44%2C41c-0.5-0.6-1.3-0.8-2-0.6%0A%09c-0.7%2C0.2-'
                                          '1.3%2C0.9-1.5%2C1.6c-0.2%2C0.8%2C0%2C1.6%2C0.5%2C2.2l1%2C1.2H22.8c-1%2C0'
                                          '.1-1.7%2C0.9-1.7%2C1.8v0.9c0%2C1%2C0.7%2C1.8%2C1.7%2C1.8h19.3l-1%2C1.2%0'
                                          'A%09c-0.5%2C0.6-0.7%2C1.4-0.5%2C2.2c0.2%2C0.8%2C0.7%2C1.4%2C1.5%2C1.6c0.'
                                          '7%2C0.2%2C1.5%2C0%2C2-0.6l4.6-5.1c0.8-0.9%2C0.8-2.3%2C0-3.2L44%2C41z%20M'
                                          '23.5%2C32.8%0A%09c-1%2C0.1-1.7%2C0.9-1.7%2C1.8v0.9c0%2C1%2C0.7%2C1.8%2C1'
                                          '.7%2C1.8h23.4c1-0.1%2C1.7-0.9%2C1.7-1.8v-0.9c0-1-0.7-1.8-1.7-1.9L23.5%2C'
                                          '32.8L23.5%2C32.8z%22/%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A'
                            }
          }
    response = requests.post(f'{bitrix_domain}/rest/imconnector.register?auth={access_token}', data=params)
    r = response.json()
```

в ответ от битрикса получаю

```
"json": {
    "result": {
      "error": "ICON_REQUIRED", 
      "error_description": "\u041d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u0430 \u0438\u043a\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0435\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0430", 
      "result": false
    }
```

то есть иконку он в упор не видит.
Может кто знает в чем может быть дело? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: **Код - текстом.**

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: У Вас в вопросе какой-то код приведён скриншотом. Переделайте его в текст, помогающим так будет проще, потому что его можно будет копировать и попробовать у себя. Потом, возможно, кому-то в будущем это поможет, тк поисковая выдача может выдать Ваш вопрос с потенциальными ответом, т.к. некоторые слова из поискового запроса могут быть в Вашем коде.

Comment: Ок. Благодарю за совет.

Comment: я не эксперт в python но мне почему-то кажется что у вас при конкатации строк в 'DATA_IMAGE': 'текст' 'текст' 'текст' должен быть какой-то квантификатор типа + или что-то подобное, т.к. в ином случаи ваш json явно не корректный.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. В общем проблема решена. Я честно говоря совсем не эксперт в python.  Чуть позже напишу как решилось и что можно было сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Решение  в общем то простое было. Надо было не изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовую либу для отправки запросов. Я использовал 
bitrix24-python-sdk. Там же в коде можно посмотреть, что нужно было делать с параметрами запроса.